# How does it "allow a malicious website to obtain valid credentials." - WebAuthn

Tags: webauthn, credential-reuse

I'm not entirely convinced of the importance of verifying the authenticator attestation, and I've [asked a question about it](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/275815/117932), I'm open to it, and if you want, you can post an answer at that question, but this one is specifically about "[section 13.4.9. Validating the origin of a credential](https://www.w3.org/TR/2023/WD-webauthn-3-20230927/#sctn-validating-origin)".

It says

> The Relying Party MUST NOT accept unexpected values of origin, as doing so could allow a malicious website to obtain valid credentials. ... the Relying Party's origin validation serves as an additional layer of protection in case a faulty authenticator fails to enforce credential scope

**Q**: Can we illustrate the problem that can occur with not verifying origin (during registeration to be specific), with a concrete example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example, which doesn't depend on fault or malice in the authenticator nor the client, is outlined in [section 13.4.8. Code injection attacks](https://www.w3.org/TR/2023/WD-webauthn-3-20230927/#sctn-code-injection), which is referenced in the section you mentioned:

> Malicious code could, by the credential scope rules, be hosted on a
> subdomain of the RP ID. For example, user-submitted code hosted on
> `usercontent.example.org` could exercise any credentials scoped to the
> RP ID `example.org`. If the Relying Party allows a subdomain origin when
> verifying the assertion, malicious users could use this to launch a
> man-in-the-middle attack to obtain valid authentication assertions and
> impersonate the victims of the attack.

Of course, this is also under the assumption that you verify the signature, because if you don't, any intermediate along the way (malicious client, malicious user-injected JavaScript, malicious third-party JavaScript, malicious TLS-terminating proxy, etc.) can just replace the `clientDataJSON` with any value they like.

For that and other reasons, you should always verify assertion (authentication) signatures - those are the entire point of using WebAuthn in the first place. Not all relying parties need to verify attestation signatures, though. In fact the default value of the [`attestation`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2023/WD-webauthn-3-20230927/#dom-publickeycredentialcreationoptions-attestation) parameter during registration is [`none`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2023/WD-webauthn-3-20230927/#dom-attestationconveyancepreference-none), meaning no attestation signature will be generated at all. Some extended discussion of this, but beyond the scope of this question, can be found [in WebAuthn issue #1698](https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1698#issuecomment-1035215931).

Comment: A bit of further clarification request. Why is origin verification needed during registration as described towards the beginning of the linked section? In my mistakenly-deleted self-answer, I expressed that it's similar to reusing passwords on different websites and is no big deal, I'm eager to learn the contrary.

Comment: Yeah, it's less important to verify the `origin` attribute in the registration credential, since there's nothing preventing a malicious actor from changing the `origin` to the value you expect (even if you do verify the registration signature - see [Security considerations: Attestation Limitations](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sctn-attestation-limitations)). But it's still good practice to do so anyway, even if only to prevent accidental errors.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering with an illustrative example, a bit of context first: the attack assumes an authenticator that doesn't properly scope the credential.

When an authenticator provide the same public key to 2 different websites - 1 honest, 1 malicious where the attacker resides, attacker can wait for the client to authenticate themself to the malicious website, **then** transmit that exact authentication transcript to the honest website, thereby carrying out unauthorized activities.

To mitigate it, verifying the "origin" in the assertion will prevent the malicious website from successfully forwarding the login credential to the honest server - the origin will not match the the honest server, so the honest server know not to authorize any action.

The section also says to verify the origin during registeration, but I can't think of a security risk of not verifying it, since it's similar to reusing passwords on different websites. Please do refute me on this.